# Stream JSON from Azure Cosmos DB to browser in Web API

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an HTTP endpoint for returning data directly from Azure Cosmos DB. The endpoint is basically a database access point (this seems like a common case). Since I'm returning the data unmodified, there's no need to deserialize it, even though I have an object for `Project` on the server that is used elsewhere. I'm wondering if there are any ways to make this code more efficient, or tighter.

```cs
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProjects()
{
    await ValidateUser();
    var cosmosDb = await Storage.GetCosmosDb();
    var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition($"SELECT * FROM projects project WHERE project.organization = '{CurrentUser.Organization}'");
    var projectsQuery = cosmosDb.Containers[typeof(Project)]
        .GetItemQueryStreamIterator(queryDefinition);
    var projects = new JArray();
    while (projectsQuery.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var responseMessage = await projectsQuery.ReadNextAsync();
        if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return InternalServerError(new Exception(
                $"Query item from stream failed. Status code: {responseMessage.StatusCode} Message: {responseMessage.ErrorMessage}"));
        }

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseMessage.Content))
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            var project = JObject.Load(jsonTextReader);
            ((JArray)project["Documents"]).ForEach(projects.Add);
        }
    }

    return Ok(projects);
}
```